# Poner un event listener a un objeto generado por ngFor

Tags: html, typescript

Tengo un problema, quiero poner un event listener en un td para que cuando lo cliquen se muestre un input dentro del td y además este input aparezca ya con el focus en el propio input. El problema es que esta tabla son las lineas de un array y estoy generando la tabla con un ngFor y aunque he conseguido que en una línea cuando se clique el td me aparezca el input con el focus, las otras lineas no me funcionan (supongo que al estar el id en el td este objeto con el id se replica). No se si hay alguna manera de asignar los id de manera dinámica (es la única solución que se me ocurre), pero me parece algo malo porque acabaré teniendo muchos eventListeners que según he podido leer en internet consumen recursos y pueden afectar al rendimiento de la página.

Código HTML:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let venta of lineas; let i = index" [ngClass]="selectedRow == i ? 'tr-selected' : 'tr'">
    
                    <td id="tdCantidadTabla" class="cell-lines-table" (click)="modificarCampo(i, true, 'cantidad')" width="15%">
                        <div *ngIf="selectedRow == i && colEdit == 'cantidad'">
                            <input type="text" id="cantidadTabla" value = {{keys}} [(ngModel)]="valorCelda" (blur)="modificarCampo(i, false, 'cantidad')" style="height: 35px; width: 100%">
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="selectedRow != i || colEdit != 'cantidad'">
                            {{venta.LVN_CANTIDAD}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
</tr>
```

Código del typeScript:

```
case 'cantidad': {
      this.valorCelda =  this.formatoSalida(this.lineas[i].LVN_CANTIDAD, 0);
      const el7 = document.getElementById("tdCantidadTabla");
      if (el7) {
        el7.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          console.log("hola");
          const element = document.getElementById("cantidadTabla");
          element.focus();
        });
      }
      break;
    }
```

El código que he puesto corresponde a un switch respecto al tercer argumento de la función modificar campo. Si necesitáis más información no dudéis en pedirla.

Como siempre muchas gracias por adelantado

Comment: Échale un vistazo a [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). Deberías usar las herramientas que te ofrece Angular y no agregar una capa adicional de código propio.

Comment: No entiendo, en el `td` ya tienes un click, que problema te da?

Comment: Primero de todo solo me permite hacer focus al primer input del primer input que se clica si lo haces con los otros si que los muestra pero no me hace el focus. Probé tqambien ha hacer el focus dentro del switch de la funcion que llama el click del td pero es que entonces directamente ya no funciona el focus.

Comment: tienes la funcion `(click)="modificarCampo(i, true, 'cantidad')"`, a esta función le puedes agregar el evento quedando en `(click)="modificarCampo(i, true, 'cantidad', $event)"` este $event contiene el elemento cliqueado por lo que puedes buscar el input y darle focus, la esctructura del elemento no la recuerdo pero creo que es algo como `event.nativeElement.children...`